# Proving that the Null space of a matrix consisting of multiples of two vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If matrix A= \begin{pmatrix}1&1&2\\ 1&0&0\end{pmatrix} , the vector v=\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\\ 2\end{pmatrix} and the vector w= \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix} How do I prove that Null(A) consists of all multiples of the vectors v and w?

Comment: First off, I think you probably mean "linear combinations of $v$ and $w$", rather than "multiples". Second, that's not right: $Av, Aw\neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The null space of the matrix $A$ consists of all multiples of the vector \begin{pmatrix}0\\ -2\\ 1\end{pmatrix}.